# Notification Badge in android using react native?

Tags: android, react-native, notifications

I'm new to react native, trying to implement notification badge in my project, for iOS using @react-native-community/push-notification-ios plugin to maintain the notification badge, but for android not found proper doc or plugin to implement. can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below npm package to set the notification badge count on the android app icon.

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-android-badge

Comment: What issues you are facing ?

Comment: not getting any error, unable to see the badge

Comment: are you able to get any response from the method?

Comment: no, BadgeAndroid.setBadge(10); not accessible

Comment: Have you tried running the again app by npx react-native run-android?

Comment: yes, even tried react-native-notification-badge also not working